# Custom components does not work in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, styles, mobile-application

I am new to react native and trying to make a small user input form, but my code does not work well.

I made a class that will create label and text input, but style does not work for my class, Form1. The class in the same file App.js worked, but importing from another js file did not.

Can someone help me to figure out the solution and why it happens?

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Form1 from './Parts/Form1';

export default function App() {
const [name, setName] = useState('Haruku');
const [age, setAge] = useState('30');

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.centerBox} borderWidth="1">Enter name: </Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder='Example'
                onChangeText={(val) => setName(val)} />
            <Form1 />
            <Text>name: {name}, age: {age}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#777',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
    margin: 10,
    width: 200,
},
centerBox: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 150,
},
buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
},
});
```

Form1.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Form1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles2.centerBox}>Age: </Text>
            <TextInput style={styles2.input} placeholder='Example' />
        </View>
    )
}
}

const styles2 = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#777',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
    margin: 10,
    width: 200,
    placeholder: "Ex",
},
centerBox: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
});

export default Form1;
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@zhenguet/hal03 I cant see any problem in expo if I import React in Form1.js

Comment: @Zuet I am confused...On my screen with expo, the label is not aligned, the placeholder does not show up, and any change in style in Form1 does not affect the result as well...

Comment: maybe you miss something. Please check carefully

Comment: @Zuet Okay, thank you. I appreciate that you shared the link to show the output.

Answer (score 0):

We should **import the React when we are creating any component that returns JSX**.

Have a **try by adding the below import statement on the top of the Form1.js**

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: This statement was there at the first, but deleting it did not affect the result, and I just removed it. I will add it. Do you have any other ideas?